# Is it possible to have DIV in TD without taking up a column

Tags: html, css

This is a long shot, so if it's not possible, let me know.  Basically, I hacked up a solution to have image overlay on TD row by adding a DIV in each of them and have the width set to the width of the entire row.  The effect was really good, but now I got this extra colomn taking up space from the DIV.  I was wondering if it's possible to get rid of it.  Screenshot attached.

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<tr class="event-state-edited row_selected" eventid="7c5b1bb6-1b36-489a-0000-000000006482">
    <td><!--CONTROLS--><img src="includes/edit.png" style="width:25px; height:25px;" class="bt_single_event_edit"></td>
    <td>12/12/2011 8:05:13 PM</td>
    <td>12/12/2011 8:05:43 PM</td>
    <td>Test MC5</td>
    <td>00:00:00</td>
    <td>0.5</td><td>EEEEEEEEEEEE</td>
    <td>\Conveyors\Snapped Belt</td>
    <td>undefined</td>
    <td>Secondary</td>
    <div class="table-row-overlay" style="display: inline-block; background-position-x: 221px; ">COPY</div>
</tr>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.table-row-overlay{
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black; 
    display:inline-block; 
    position:absolute; 
    width:100%; 
    height:48px; 
    left:-1px; 
    background-image:url('includes/overlay.png'); 
    overflow:hidden;
    filter:alpha(opacity=20);
    opacity:0.20;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or a live site for us to work with.

Comment: a TR element is not allowed to contain a DIV element.  Why not add the table-row-overlay class to the desired TR element in your table?

Comment: Do you want the overlay to cover the cells, or are you just trying to replicate a background effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I did not find a way to make a column not take up space in a table.

So I moved the DIV outside of TD, get rid of the extra column and just positioned the DIV absolutely to be directly over the TD row.  I use jQuery to determine the offset position to place it.

Answer (score 0):

It'll require some re-styling in the CSS, but I'd recommend adding the `div` inside of one of the `td` elements.  As it stands, a `div` element alongside a `td` in a `tr` isn't really valid to begin with.

Or maybe give it its own `td` (to logically separate it from the others) and style the `div` to display as it does now while styling its parent `td` to not display.

Answer (score 0):

instead of an image try using `css` alone.  `css3 gradients` with `:hover` or use `jQuery` to `.addClass()` depending on your desired user experience.